# Why does TokuDB impose a limit of 64 keys per table?

Tags: tokudb

Why does TokuDB impose a limit of 64 keys per table by default,
while systems like Elasticsearch allow any number of fields to be indexed (limited only by available resources)?

Answer (score 2):

Short answer, because at some point you simply need to put limits in your software. TokuDB is a storage engine for MySQL which supports far more operations than Elasticsearch, so there are trade-offs to be considered. Since TokuDB is open source I'd imagine you could find this value somewhere in the source code and raise it to something higher, compile, test, and deploy.

Comment: It makes sense that there have to be trade-offs, but I'm curious about any specifics as far as - what SQL operations would be negatively impacted by allowing > 64 indexes, and adding the few extra bytes of metadata keep track of them?

Comment: Every index you add increases the work for DML. Ex: table with no index, an insert is an insert into one tree; with one index, one insert into two trees (2x work); with two indexes, one insert into three trees (3x work); etc. Then take into account updates. Updates that alter a part of a key are not updates, but one delete and one insert. Another consideration is how useful really are extra indexes and if MySQL optimizer can legitimately make a decision to use one over another for any particular query. Also, as I said below, the limit is a MySQL compile time imposed limit, not a TokuDB limit.

Answer (score 0):

This is a MySQL limit, grep MAX_INDEXES